# PHP html table with Foreach loop and If condition

Tags: php

I'm working on a booking system and I want my users to be able to see their bookings. I'm using a foreach loop to echo all the bookings. However, the last two columns have a 0-1 value and I want to echo something else based on that value or hide something altogether.

Here's the loop:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach ($row as $value) { 
        echo "<td>" . $value . "</td>"; 
    }
}
```

And here are the conditions:

```
if($row['status']== 'To pay'){
    echo '<td>
            <form action="./payments/index.php" method="post">
                <button class="pay" type="submit" name="submit" style="background: linear-gradient(-145deg, rgba(255, 216, 133,1) 0%, rgba(245, 164, 37,1) 100%);">Pay Now!</button>
            </form>
        </td>';
}else{
    echo '<th>Paid</th>';
}
if($row['modified']=='no'){
    echo '<td>';
    echo '<form action="modify.php?id='.$row['Id'].'" method="post">
            <button class="modify" id="myBtnM" type="submit" name="submit" style="background: linear-gradient(-145deg, rgba(255, 216, 133,1) 0%, rgba(245, 164, 37,1) 100%);">Modify</button>
            </form>';
    echo '</td>';
    echo '<td>';
    echo '<form action="cancel.php" method="post">
            <button class="cancel" id="myBtnC" type="submit" name="submit" onclick="return checkDelete()" style="background: linear-gradient(-145deg, rgba(255, 216, 133,1) 0%, rgba(245, 164, 37,1) 100%);">Cancel</button>
            </form>';
    echo '</td>';
}
```

So, the loop works, but the if statement only echoes one row. I tried everything I could think of, but I'm a beginner and I can find a solution. If I add the if statement inside the loop, it echoes one entry forever. Same if it is inside the while loop only.
I search on here and google, but I couldn't find anything that helps.
If this has been answered already, please point me towards it, and my apologies.

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: Please share the part where you "add the if statement inside the loop". Likely the `foreach` is causing issues for you. That usually is not done, just write the cells as you'd want. You also never close the row so that could affect your display

Comment: Are those tests INSIDE the WHILE loop. It looks to me like they ought to be, but it does not look like that is where you have coded them

Comment: Slightly off-topic, but you shouldn't really be storing status codes as strings like "to pay" - use a status code and if you need to, look the string values up elsewhere. Similarly for the issue you're having, if the 0 / 1 values are always the same, you could stick the values and their associated names in a separate table and retrieve them as part of your query using a JOIN.

Comment: Its not totally clear what you have coded and how/where the code is. Its also not really clear what you are trying to achieve

Comment: _However, the last two columns have a 0-1 value and I want to echo something else_ So which are those last 2 columns and what do you want to show instead of a 0 or 1 in each case

Comment: Thank you all! To answer a few: I changed the 0/1 values  into paid/to pay because I had troubles with echoing the correct names to the corresponding values. @RiggsFolly: my mistake, I changed the code and got confused, the columns 'status' and 'modified' should be the 0/1. I have tried inside the while loop but didn't work as it was. I'll take on your suggestion on indentation! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test the column name in the loop so you can use the special code for the `status` and `modified` columns.

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach ($row as $key => $value) { 
        if ($key == 'status') {
            if($value == 'To pay'){
                echo '<td>
                          <form action="./payments/index.php" method="post">
                              <button class="pay" type="submit" name="submit" style="background: linear-gradient(-145deg, rgba(255, 216, 133,1) 0%, rgba(245, 164, 37,1) 100%);">Pay Now!</button>
                          </form>
                      </td>';
            }else{
                echo '<th>Paid</th>';
            }
        } elseif ($key == 'modified') {
            if ($value == 'no') {
                echo '<td>';
                echo '<form action="modify.php?id='.$row['Id'].'" method="post">
                              <button class="modify" id="myBtnM" type="submit" name="submit" style="background: linear-gradient(-145deg, rgba(255, 216, 133,1) 0%, rgba(245, 164, 37,1) 100%);">Modify</button>
                          </form>';
                echo '</td>';
                echo '<td>';
                echo '<form action="cancel.php" method="post">
                              <button class="cancel" id="myBtnC" type="submit" name="submit" onclick="return checkDelete()" style="background: linear-gradient(-145deg, rgba(255, 216, 133,1) 0%, rgba(245, 164, 37,1) 100%);">Cancel</button>
                          </form>';
                echo '</td>';
            }
        } else {
            echo "<td>" . $value . "</td>"; 
        }
    }
}
```